# How to read input file name in piglatin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have standard prefixes in filenames (QWERTY_123,POIUY_029 etc.,) which have same delimiters all the time. QWERTY ->, POIUY ->; I developed a udf which takes prefix and tells the delimiter. Now how to read files names in pig so that I split prefix from file name and get delimiter to load files properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PigStorage` clause in your `LOAD` statement, as outlined in item 2 of [this post](http://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/pigstorage-options-schema-and-source-tagging/). It will put the filename as the first field in each record:

```
A = LOAD 'input' using PigStorage(',','-tagsource'); 
B = foreach A generate $0 as input_filename;
```

Comment: Thank you. This code scans through all the records in the file and gives file names as many times as no. of records exists in the file [foreach A]. I have two input files in input directory, I just need two file names.`QWERTY_123.csv,POIUY_029.txt` I need only QWERTY_123 and POIUY_029 in the output